# Protractor: is there a way to use element.all on a previously located element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Is there a way to use element.all (find an array of elements) on a previously selected element ?

I'd like to:

```
element(by.model('c.item.state')).element.all(by.css('option')).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is

```
element(by.model('c.item.state')).all(by.css('option')).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a single css-selector to avoid having to chain them together.
`element.all(by.css("[ng-model='c.item.state'] .option")).count()`

Comment: Thank you - I felt I wanted to make the hierarchy explicit, with separate selectors(types). However, this solution looks good in that aspect, too